# Couldn't bind UDP 53 nxfilter

Tags: 14.04, networking, bind

We are using ubuntu 14.04 and successfully installed nxfilter latest version. When I run the *./startup.sh* script file then getting below error:

```
INFO - ResolverMan.create_resolver, Resolving DNS server : [8.8.8.8,   8.8.4.4]
INFO - Reset user_quota.
INFO - Loading user_quota.
INFO - RequestHandler started.
INFO - UdpServer started.
ERROR - UdpServer: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
INFO - Couldn't bind UDP 53. You might want to check your permission!
```

Comment: Ubuntu runs `dnsmasq` as a local DNS resolver, so that will likely already be bound to port 53

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable Dnsmasq.

You need to edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file

```
gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and comment out the following line from

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

to

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

Save and exit the file

Now you need to network-manager using the following command or just reboot

```
sudo restart network-manager
```